# Regex to split string into separate keys

Tags: javascript, regex

Working on a bit of an interesting project and I'm having a little trouble writing regex for this.

Using regex and Javascript, I want to split my input string into an array of "keys".  Strings that have an invalid key should return 0 keys (null, empty array, whatever is fine).

#### The "spec"

```
<input string>      => <matches>

# named keys
a                   => ['a']
b                   => ['b']
foo[bar]            => ['foo', 'bar']

# numeric keys are ok too
a[0]                => ['a', '0']
b[1]                => ['b', '1']

# 'push' syntax is also valid
push[]              => ['push', '']
hello[]             => ['hello', '']

# complex!
complex[named][0][] => ['complex', 'named', '0', '']
```

#### Invalid examples

```
# named keys must start with [a-zA-Z]
_invalid            => null
3foo[abc]           => null

# named keys can include a number as long as they start with a letter
foo3valid[this_is_valid_2] => ['foo3valid', 'this_is_valid_2']
```

#### What I have so far

```js
var regex = /^(?:\[?([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*|[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\]?)+$/g;
var keys = [];

myInput.replace(regex, function(match,capture,pos,source){
    keys.push(capture);
});

console.log(myInput, keys);
```

#### How it fails

My regex is matching only the last "key" E.g.,

```
# should be ['a', 'b', 'c']
a[b][c]   => ['c']
```

#### Tinker on jsFiddle

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MVJZc/)

Comment: I'm getting ['c'] with your regex against 'a[b][c]'.

Comment: @MikePartridge I added a jsFiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/MVJZc/

Comment: @MikePartridge, I had a false positive result in a different test.  You're right, the regex above only captures the last key. (I updated the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken another approach to get the desired results:

1. Test whether the given phrase is valid.
2. If valid, use a global match to create an array.

Code: **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MVJZc/2/**

```
///Example
var myInput = "a[b][][c]";

var validate = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?:\[(?:\d*|[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\])*$/,
    pattern = /[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|(?=\[\])/g,
    //(?=\[\]) is used to create an empty entry for []
    keys = null;
if (validate.test(myInput)) {
    keys = myInput.match(pattern);
}
```

Note: If you want to extend the pattern, e.g. to include the `$` character, modify the first RegEx. The second RegEx (`pattern`) should at least contain all valid characters.

Comment: This is getting close, but some inputs aren't passing.  See results here: http://jsfiddle.net/MVJZc/3/

Comment: @macek Use my fiddle. My very first answer (which you've used for your fiddle) was missing the `+` sign at the `validate` pattern. http://jsfiddle.net/MVJZc/2/

Comment: By the way, use `/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?:\[(?:\d*|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\])*$/` if a `[...]` may only start with a digit if it's only consisting of digits, or `/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?:\[[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\])*$/` if `b[3ab]` is also valid.

Answer (score 1):

would something like this work?

```
var input = "a[b][c]";
input = input.replace(/[\[\]]$/,"").replace(/[\]\[]+/g,"|");
var args = input.split("|");
```

And here's a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/vZBtj/

Comment: This does not validate each key. It's only validating the first one.  E.g., `foo[_invalid]` and `foo[bar][ fails2]` should not return keys.

Comment: @macek I see... I would go back and fix it but it seems you found an answer already. :P

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility, definitely not as succinct as Rob W's, but get's the job done ;-)

```
function parseThing(aStr){
    var res = [];
    success = false;
    if(aStr.indexOf('[') > 0){
        var idx = aStr.indexOf('[');
        var first = aStr.substring(0, idx);
        if(first.match(/\w/)){
            success = true;
            res.push(first);

            //now parse stuff inside brackets
            var rest = aStr.substring(idx, aStr.length-1);
            var arr = rest.split("]");
            for(i in arr){
                res.push(arr[i].replace("[", ""));
            }
        }
    } else if(aStr.match(/\w/)){
        res.push(aStr);
    }
    return res;
}

console.log(parseThing("a[a][b]"));
console.log(parseThing("a"));
console.log(parseThing("b"));
console.log(parseThing("foo[bar] "));
console.log(parseThing("a[0]"));
console.log(parseThing("b[1]"));
console.log(parseThing("complex[named][0][]"));
```